# How to use Bootstrap's bg-variant modifier

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

I have some buttons

```
<button type="button" class="myButton btn btn-primary">foo</button>
<button type="button" class="myButton btn btn-secondary">bar</button>
...
```

For the background colors of which I'd like to give some transparency. I'm trying like:

```
button.myButton {
  @include bg-variant(<???>, rgba(<button's color?>, 0.7));
}
```

There are some infos [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/#modifiers) and [there](https://martijncuppens.github.io/bootstrap-mixins-documentation/docs/4.1/mixins/#bg-variant) although not much about it.

**Update:**

I'm getting closer... Replacing the above SCSS code by:

```
@include bg-variant('button.myButton', rgba($red, 0.7));
```

does the trick, but here I explicitly set the color to red. I'd like to make it dynamic, so use the given button's color here instead.

**Update 2:**

I thought I've finally found it, but this:

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  @include bg-variant('button.myButton', rgba($value, 0.7));
}
```

makes my buttons' background just gray. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  @include bg-variant('button.myButton.btn-#{$color}", rgba($value, 0.7));
}
```

Comment: `bg-variant` is deprecated and will be removed in v5

Comment: I've seen this warning too, the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#modifiers) however still feature it and no alternatives are mentioned.